# rails 3 how can i give permissions to user for specific task like tickets, messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i am new to rails and i want to give permissions to users for particular task involved in my project on different modules.

i have two models "user" and "project"... in "user.rb" has_many : projects
and in "project.rb" belongs_to :user. and i have one more model which combine both models named "user_project.rb" in this model have proj_id an user_id stored.

i want to give permission and after that also check for the permission to current user for creating messages and tasks according to permissions assign to them.

where can i define  permissions and how it works for me in view as well....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created user_project.rb only for storing these ids - remove it.

This look like you need to write before_filter in your controllers

```rb
class ProjectsController << ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user_required, only: [ :edit, :update ]

  #there def of actions

  private 

  def current_user_required
    unless current_user == @project.user
      flash[:error] = 'error 403'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

And when you find @project, for edit and update actions, you can do it like:

```rb
@project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id]) #need to change :project_id
```

If you want to create model Message(belongs_to :project and Project has_name: messages) and give access for creation and edit it only for project.user you can do it using before_filter or validation in model

```rb
class Message << ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :author_is_project_user, on: :create

  private

  def author_is_project_user
    errors.add :base, 'author not is project user' unless self.author == self.project.user
  end
end
```

According to this you can define permission for another things

And if you want to get permission for another user you have_to create model which belongs_ to :user and :project and check in before_filter present of it.

sort of this:

```rb
class Permission << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project

  scope :about, -> project { where project_id: project }
  scope :of_user, -> user { where project_id: project }
end
```

and in User model define method like

```rb
def access_to_project? project
  Permission.about(project).of_user(self).first.present?
end
```

or you can add variable to this model and make more complicated logic of access

Comment: so no need to define another model for permissions? i have three roles for message permissions. "manage" can do all task, "read" and "read and write". per user it will be different so how could i manage all them.

Comment: Thanks this quite work for me :) do u have any idea about ajax?